# Convert a Tensorflow MapDataset to a tf.TensorArray

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Suppose I have the following code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

simple_data_samples = np.array([
         [1, 1, 1, -1, -1],
         [2, 2, 2, -2, -2],
         [3, 3, 3, -3, -3],
         [4, 4, 4, -4, -4],
         [5, 5, 5, -5, -5],
         [6, 6, 6, -6, -6],
         [7, 7, 7, -7, -7],
         [8, 8, 8, -8, -8],
         [9, 9, 9, -9, -9],
         [10, 10, 10, -10, -10],
         [11, 11, 11, -11, -11],
         [12, 12, 12, -12, -12],
])

def timeseries_dataset_multistep_combined(features, label_slice, input_sequence_length, output_sequence_length, batch_size):
    feature_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(features, None, input_sequence_length + output_sequence_length, batch_size=batch_size)

    def split_feature_label(x):
        x=tf.strings.as_string(x)

        return x[:, :input_sequence_length, :], x[:, input_sequence_length:, label_slice]

    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(split_feature_label)

    return feature_ds

ds = timeseries_dataset_multistep_combined(simple_data_samples, slice(None, None, None), input_sequence_length=4, output_sequence_length=2,
batch_size=1)
def print_dataset(ds):
    for inputs, targets in ds:
        print("---Batch---")
        print("Feature:", inputs.numpy())
        print("Label:", targets.numpy())
        print("")



print_dataset(ds)
```

The variable ds denotes a Tensorflow MapDataset. I would like to convert this variable ds into a tf.TensorArray. What would be the fastest and most efficient way?

Comment: ` list(ds)`  ??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the output of the iterator as-is, here is the code.

```
list_array = list(sum(list(ds),()))
feature = tf.squeeze(tf.stack(list_array[::2]))
label = tf.squeeze(tf.stack(list_array[1::2]))
```